# remove entry in counter object if value meets condition

Tags: python, counter

Is there a way to remove entries from a counter object if the value matches a certain condition. For example:

```
Counter({'a': 1142,'b':1004,'c':100,'d':5})
```

I want to drop all indexes where it is less than 1000, so I just have 'a' and 'b' left. I know I can loop through each and then delete if it doesnt match the condition as shown in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7154312/how-do-i-remove-entries-within-a-counter-object-with-a-loop-without-invoking-a-r). Just looking for a more efficient way.

Comment: Are you asking about an arbitrary condition, or specifically about a comparison with a threshold value?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I currently need a comparison for specifically a threshold value, but would be interested in seeing both if they defer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be useful for you:

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter({'a': 1142, 'b': 1004, 'c': 100, 'd':5})
Counter({k: c for k, c in counter.items() if c >= 1000})
```

Output:

```
Counter({'a':1142 , 'b': 1004})
```

This way is more effective as you mentioned.

Comment: How do you know that it is more effective?

Comment: Because `"For loop" is around 50% slower than a list comprehension` according to https://switowski.com/blog/for-loop-vs-list-comprehension/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop to delete the keys in place:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter({'a': 1142,'b':1004,'c':100,'d':5})

for k in list(c):
    if c[k] < 1000:
        del c[k]

print(c)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'a': 1142, 'b': 1004})
```

If you want a copy:

```
c2 = Counter({k:v for k,v in c.items() if v>= 1000})
```

Comment: I know you can use a loop, I was wondering if there was a better solution to it.

Comment: How do you define "*better*" what limitations have you encountered?

Comment: mainly one that has a faster run time.

Comment: If you're fine with a copy, the dictionary comprehension (see my second example) will be faster. If you want the original object, you have to use a classical loop