# Alternative triple for Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to loop through a three-dimensional array. Is there any alternative method which is more efficient (or faster) than the following?

```
for i, j, k in itertools.product(*map(xrange, (len(x), len(y), len(z))))
```

In this example, x, y and z are three one-dimensional arrays.

My source code is this, I do not want  the value of lists.

```
for i, j, k in itertools.product(*map(xrange, (len(x0), len(y0), len(z0)))):
       print "p[%d][%d][%d] = %d" % (x0[i], y0[j], z0[k], p[i][j][k])
```

`p` being the 3d-array

Comment: I explain evil, edit my post, sorry

Comment: You do use the values of the list: `x0[i], y0[j], z0[k]` retrieves those values.

Comment: Any time you find yourself combining `range` (or `xrange` in 2.x) and `len`, *stop* and think about what you are doing. [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4383321/523612).

Comment: You're doing nothing but printing out the values of the 3 lists, not actually using them to index the `p` array. Thus, your `print` is misleading. It would be more accurate for it to be `print "p[%d][%d][%d] = %d" % (i, j, k, p[i][j][k])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the x, y, & z lists, so the following ways of looping through the array, with and without indices, are all more efficient in the sense that they don't use them:

```
import itertools
from pprint import pprint

W,H,D = 3,4,5
p = [[[k*W*H + j*W+i for i in xrange(3)] for j in xrange(4)] for k in xrange(5)]
assert (W,H,D) == (len(p[0][0]),len(p[0]),len(p))
pprint(p)

print
for i, j, k in itertools.product(xrange(D), xrange(H), xrange(W)):
    print "p[%d][%d][%d] = %d" % (i, j, k, p[i][j][k])
print
for i in xrange(D):
    for j in xrange(H):
        for k in xrange(W):
            print "p[%d][%d][%d] = %d" % (i, j, k, p[i][j][k])
print
for col in p:
    for row in col:
        for elem in row:
            print elem
print
for i, col in enumerate(p):
    for j, row in enumerate(col):
        for k, elem in enumerate(row):
            print "p[%d][%d][%d] = %d" % (i, j, k, elem)
```

Answer (score 6):

Why not just loop over the lists *themselves* instead?

```
for i, j, k in itertools.product(x, y, z):
```

You do not have indices now, you have the actual values:

```
>>> x, y, z = range(3), range(3, 6), range(6, 9)
>>> for i, j, k in itertools.product(x, y, z):
...     print i, j, k
... 
0 3 6
0 3 7
0 3 8
0 4 6
# .. ~ ..
2 4 8
2 5 6
2 5 7
2 5 8
```

If you *have* to have the indices too, just use `enumerate()`:

```
>>> for (ii, i), (jj, j), (kk, k) in itertools.product(*map(enumerate, (x, y, z))):
...     print (ii, i), (jj, j), (kk, k)
... 
(0, 0) (0, 3) (0, 6)
(0, 0) (0, 3) (1, 7)
(0, 0) (0, 3) (2, 8)
(0, 0) (1, 4) (0, 6)
# .. ~ ..
(2, 2) (1, 4) (2, 8)
(2, 2) (2, 5) (0, 6)
(2, 2) (2, 5) (1, 7)
(2, 2) (2, 5) (2, 8)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this

```
for i in x:
  for j in y:
    for k in z:
      print i,j,k
```